# Share scipy.sparse arrays with zero-copy in Python's Ray

Tags: python, scipy, multiprocessing, shared-memory, ray

I pass large [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) arrays to a parallel processes on shared memory of one computing node. In each round of parallel jobs, the passed array will not be modified. I want to pass the array with zero-copy.

While this is possible with [multiprocessing.RawArray()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray) and numpy.sharedmem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes?rq=1)), I am wondering how [ray's put()](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/package-ref.html#ray.put) works.

As far as I understood (see [memory management](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/memory-management.html), [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580947/python3-multiprocess-shared-numpy-arrayread-only/54583841#54583841)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270503/using-shared-array-in-multiprocessing?noredirect=1&lq=1)]), ray's put() copies the object *once* and for all (serialize, then de-serialize) to the object store that is available for all processes.

*Question:*

I am not sure I understood it correctly, is it a deep copy of the entire array in the object store or just a reference to it? Is there a way to "not" copy the object at all? Rather, just pass the address/reference of the existing scipy array? Basically, a true shallow copy without the overhead of copying the entire array.

---

Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.7.6, Ray 0.8.5.

Comment: This can be also helpful to understand how zero-copy read works https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serialization.html?highlight=zero%20copy#serialization

Comment: `scipy.sparse` matrix is not a `ndarray` subclass.  It's a custom Python class, or rather classes.  Different formats have different classes and data storage attributes. One is actually a dictionary subclass, the others store the data (and indices) in several `ndarrays`.

Comment: @hpaulj that's no problem I can pass components of scipy sparse array like non-zero data and their indices as ndarray.